# Java Future<V> interface- what will get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) return?

Tags: java, concurrency, timeout

The documentation is a bit confusing. What will the method return if there is a time out? The documentation says "the computed result", but what if the computation has timed out? is it null?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the computation times out it will throw a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

From the Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html):

> Exception thrown when a blocking operation times out. Blocking
>   operations for which a timeout is specified need a means to indicate
>   that the timeout has occurred. For many such operations it is possible
>   to return a value that indicates timeout; when that is not possible or
>   desirable then TimeoutException should be declared and thrown.

Comment: sure, but I have to wait, you were too fast ;-)